# getLogger() не работает

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package teleport.main;

import java.lang.System.Logger;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class teleport extends JavaPlugin {
    
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("123");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @insolor   он есть

Comment: В приведенном вами коде его нет. Почитайте ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и добавьте в вопрос весь необходимый код.

Comment: @insolor чекните новый скрин

Comment: и с this он тоже не работает

Comment: Я посмотрел что такое [org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.java), там этот метод есть. Если у вас все компилируется, но этот код не вызывается (в лог ничего не пишется), то возможно не создается объект этого класса.

Comment: В общем, голосую за закрытие вопроса, потому что недостаточно данных для ответа. Не работает - что у вас означает? не компилируется (ошибка компиляции) или не пишет в лог? Если не компилируется - приведите ошибку в вопросе. Если не пишет в лог - покажите в вопросе, как этот код используется. Если он откуда-то снаружи используется (вы его сами не вызываете) - добавьте ссылку на документацию, либо какой-то другой текст, где будет откуда будет понятно "куда коней запрягать".

Answer (score 0):

1. `System.Logger` работает только для JDK >= 9
2. Инициация логгера производится через `Logger logger=System.getLogger("mylogger");`, далее уже можно вызывать `logger.info("123")`